# Setting the html source of an element with content containing image tag

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using the [Mootools History plugin](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-history) to update the content of a page without requiring the page to be reloaded.

Everything works fine except for Mootools generating a 404 error (visible in the console) when an image is in the content being injected.

The content is gathered and set via a Request.HTML call as follows (simplified demo):

```
var request = new Request.JSON({
    onSuccess: function(responseJSON, responseText) {
        html = JSON.decode(responseJSON);
        $('zone').set('html', html['text']);
    }
});
```

The content is being set correctly however the `.set('html', content)` seems to generate a 404 error by rewriting the `src` attributes of images.

The urls look like this:

```
http://example.com/%22//files//images//ImageName.jpg/%22
```

Whilst the page source shows them as:

```
/files/images/ImageName.jpg
```

The 404 error refers to **line 334** in the Mootools Core, though I can't see quite where that would cause the issue.

Comment: er what? you don't use Request but use Request.HTML then you try to serialize a html collection of element objects by converting it to a json? this is wrong on many levels. try using Request() and then `$('zone').set(html, this.response.text)`

Comment: @DimitarChristoff I've changed it to use Request.JSON since that's the format I'm using, however that doesn't solve my problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `Request.JSON` rather than `Request.HTML` and to access the JSON object directly rather than decoding it first.

i.e.

```
var request = new Request.JSON({
    onSuccess: function(responseJSON, responseText) {
        $('zone').set('html', responseJSON.text);
    }
});
```

As suggested in part by [@DimitarChristoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126998/dimitar-christoff)

Comment: fair enough - we have no way of magically knowing what your data actually comes as or what keys will contain your output string. :) glad it works for you now